# How do i write a .htaccess file that contains a default index AND redirect concerning the same home page?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a website I'm building for someone. The directory structure is such that I need the `.htaccess` file to return the default home page (`/home.php`) when someone types `www.mydoamin.co.uk` in an address bar but ALSO redirect people all ready on the site RETURNING to the home page to `www.mydoamin.co.uk`.

I basically just want one version of my home page which is to be `www.mydomain.co.uk` as opposed to `www.mydomain.co.uk/home.php` - and I need to do it in one `.htaccess` file. Is this possible?

Currently I’ve got

```
#default index page
DirectoryIndex home.php
Redirect /home.php http://mydomain.co.uk
```

This just returns an index of the directory though - as if it's only parsed once possibly? I don't know.

Each of these statements used on their own in the file have the desired affect but I can't combine them.

Comment: This seems very complicated for no benefit. What’s wrong with an **index.php** page, like most other websites?

Comment: i dont get this. if you use the `DirectoryIndex home.php` command in your .htacces it will solve your problem. you dont need the redirect, just point the homepage link to mydomain.co.uk

Comment: the redirect is intended for people who are on say mydomain.co.uk/sometherpage.html who click on 'home' in the nav bar. The href attribute in the link in the nav bar is "mydomain.co.uk/home.php". Could i just change this href to "mydomain.co.uk" and let the default page index do the rest? I guess a browser would accept it as a valid href. I'm doing this for some fairly basic SEO purposes

Comment: @ martin I don't want any file name in the url when your on the home page. I might be wrong but wouldn't changing the filename to index.php only leave me with the same problem? I'll have 2 pages indexed by google because the server will serve 'www.mydomain.co.uk' when searching direct in google and mydomain.co.uk/index.php when returning to the home page through the nav bar.

Comment: just tested it with absolute URLs in the nav bar that link to just the domain and not the specific file eg /home.php.  Works fine. Sorry if it was a daft question to ask. Its the first full site Ive built